# C++ array vs C# ptr speed confusion

Tags: c#, c++, arrays, performance

I am rewriting a high performance C++ application to C#. The C# app is noticeably slower than the C++ original. Profiling tells me that the C# app spends most time in accessing array elements. Hence I create a simple array access benchmark. I get completely different results than [others doing a similiar comparison](http://www.yankeerino.com/cpp_vs_csharp_arrays.bhs).

The C++ code:

```
#include <limits>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <chrono>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;
using namespace std::chrono;

int main(void)
{
    high_resolution_clock::time_point t1 = high_resolution_clock::now();

    int xRepLen = 100 * 1000;
    int xRepCount = 1000;

    unsigned short * xArray = new unsigned short[xRepLen];
    for (int xIdx = 0; xIdx < xRepLen; xIdx++)
        xArray[xIdx] = xIdx % USHRT_MAX;

    int * xResults = new int[xRepLen];

    for (int xRepIdx = 0; xRepIdx < xRepCount; xRepIdx++)
    {

        // in each repetition, find the first value, that surpasses xArray[xIdx] + 25 - i.e. we will perform 25 searches
        for (int xIdx = 0; xIdx < xRepLen; xIdx++)
        {
            unsigned short xValToBreach = (xArray[xIdx] + 25) % USHRT_MAX;
            xResults[xIdx] = 0;

            for (int xIdx2 = xIdx + 1; xIdx2 < xRepLen; xIdx2++)
            if (xArray[xIdx2] >= xValToBreach)
            {
                xResults[xIdx] = xIdx2; break;
            }

            if (xResults[xIdx] == 0)
                xResults[xIdx] = INT_MAX;
        }
    }

    high_resolution_clock::time_point t2 = high_resolution_clock::now();
    auto duration = duration_cast<milliseconds>(t2 - t1).count();
    cout << "Elasped miliseconds " << duration;
    getchar();
}
```

The C# code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Diagnostics;

namespace arrayBenchmarkCs
{
    class Program
    {
        public static void benchCs()
        {
            unsafe
            {
                int xRepLen = 100 * 1000;
                int xRepCount = 1000;

                ushort[] xArr = new ushort[xRepLen];
                for (int xIdx = 0; xIdx < xRepLen; xIdx++)
                    xArr[xIdx] = (ushort)(xIdx % 0xffff);

                int[] xResults = new int[xRepLen];

                Stopwatch xSw = new Stopwatch(); xSw.Start();
                fixed (ushort * xArrayStart = & xArr [0])
                {
                    for (int xRepIdx = 0; xRepIdx < xRepCount; xRepIdx++)
                    {

                        // in each repetition, go find the first value, that surpasses xArray[xIdx] + 25 - i.e. we will perform 25 searches
                        ushort * xArrayEnd = xArrayStart + xRepLen;
                        for (ushort* xPtr = xArrayStart; xPtr != xArrayEnd; xPtr++)
                        {
                            ushort xValToBreach = (ushort)((*xPtr + 25) % 0xffff);
                            int xResult = -1;
                            for (ushort * xPtr2 = xPtr + 1; xPtr2 != xArrayEnd; xPtr2++)
                                if ( *xPtr2  >= xValToBreach)
                                {
                                    xResult = (int)(xPtr2 - xArrayStart);
                                    break;
                                }

                            if (xResult == -1)
                                xResult = int.MaxValue;

                            // save result
                            xResults[xPtr - xArrayStart] = xResult;
                        }
                    }
                }   // fixed

                xSw.Stop();

                Console.WriteLine("Elapsed miliseconds: " + (xSw.ElapsedMilliseconds.ToString("0"));
            }
        }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            benchCs();
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

On my work computer (i7-3770), the C++ version is approx 2x faster than the C# version. On my home computer (i7-5820K) the C++ is 1.5x faster than the C# version. Both are measured in Release. I hoped that by using pointers in C# I would avoid the array boundary checking and the performance would be the same in both languages.

So my questions are the following:

- home come others are finding C# to be of the same speed as C++?
- how can I get C# performance to the C++ level if not via pointers?
- what could be the driver of different speedups on different computers?

Any hint is much appreciated, 
Daniel

Comment: I hope you are executing the benchmark without the debugger (CTRL+F5 instead of F5 in Visual Studio)

Comment: @xanatos: Yes. Thanks for the shortcut though.

Comment: *ushort * xArrayEnd = xArrayStart + xRepLen;* You can move this outside the `for` cycle

Comment: @xanatos: Indeed, the performance difference stays intact, however.

Comment: The author of the benchmark you linked looks biased in favour of C# over C++. This plus the fact that he doesn't share the benchmark code looks fishy... Finally, `std::vector::operator[]()` does not check boundaries. `std::vector::at()` does, he's wrong all along.

Comment: The C++ optimizer does a lovely job on this code.  What kills the C# perf primarily is ushort[] (it must promote to int to compare), the very ugly conversion of the pointer difference to *int* (don't help too much, use an uint loop variable) and having too many variables.  The latter is the biggest problem, it doesn't enregister the xPtr variable.  That can be worked around but the code changes are very artificial, you have to move the inner loops into a separate method and pass pointers to the method.

Comment: @HansPassant: I thought of the effect of working with ushort instead of uint and ... the effect is not so large. Specfically on my work box: array of ushort - 3207 ms, array of uint - 3685 ms, array of int and ints everywhere - 3068 ms. You're right, there is some effect, thanks for that! About the latter part (enregistering of xPtr) and the rest ... does this kind of manipulation have a name? Your response would lead me to ask "how does moving the inner loops into a separate method help" but it will probably be more efficient if I google, once I know what keyword to google for. Thanks!

Comment: When asking about run-time performance, it never helps to state exactly compiler, version and *all* options you use. And also the machine on which you run the binaries.

Comment: Generic name is "register allocation optimization".  Do keep in mind that you don't have a knob to tweak to directly affect the choices the optimizer makes.  The only thing that really works is to not give it too much choice so it can't make a bad one.  That's difficult in a hand-optimized C# program, those *fixed* pointers do swallow up another register.  Otherwise why moving the inner loops in a method that takes those pointers as an argument is a workaround.

Comment: @ChristianHackl: Sorry about that. The machines are i7-3770/i7-5820K with Win7 x64, compiler Visual Studio 2013 and the compiler options are the default ones.

Comment: @DanielBencik: When you say "default ones" it's still entirely unclear if you mean the compiler defaults or the IDE defaults for one of the two default option sets ("Debug" or "Release"). Why not just put the compiler-invocation line into the question?

Comment: @ChristianHackl: Right, sorry about that: /noconfig /unsafe+ /nowarn:1701,1702,2008 /nostdlib+ /platform:anycpu32bitpreferred /errorreport:prompt /warn:4 /define:TRACE /errorendlocation /preferreduilang:en-US /highentropyva+ /debug:pdbonly /filealign:512 /optimize+ /out:obj\Release\cs.exe /subsystemversion:6.00 /target:exe

Comment: Why do you even try to port a fast C++ algorithm to C#? The standard way to do is the following: Write a dynamic library (.dll for windows or .so for linux), containing the fast C++ stuff. Use this library in your fancy C# application

Answer (score 0):

You won't get this kind of hardcore number crunching to C++ speed. Using pointer arithmetic and unsafe code gets you some of the way there (it's almost half as slow again if you remove the unsafe and fixed parts). C# isn't compiled to native code, and the code that it is running is full of extra checks and stuff.

If you're willing to go `unsafe` then really there's nothing stopping you coding your C++ performance-critical stuff into a mixed-mode assembly, and calling that from your C# glue code.

Comment: Thanks for pointing me in that direction. The (small amount of) articles I have read point to the fact that the runtime switch from managed to unmanaged code and back is slow. Is that really so in your experience?

Comment: It's not like doing it once takes a long time, but doing it a lot of times in a loop would be bad. Ideally you get everything ready in C#, then hand that all off to C++ and it can do all the looping and maths. Then it packages those results back up and you can go back to all the benefits of the managed world, having done your calculations nice and fast.

Answer (score 0):

C++ code is not working the same way as C#. The inner loop is different.  There are 4 memory operations xResults[xIdx] and just 1 in c#.

I was shocked, that performance of C# code depends so much on framework version.
What's even more interesting C# on .net core 3.1 outperformed C++ by 5%. With other frameworks I checked C# was 30-50% slower then C++

Comment: are you using the same code from the question? did you try with different lengths? Could you show some detailed results?

Comment: No, I had to change C++ code to work exactly like c#. I didn't try different lengths, but I tried more repetitions - same results.

Comment: changed fragment:
`for (unsigned short* xPtr = xArray; xPtr != xArrayEnd; ++xPtr)`
    `{`
     ` unsigned short xValToBreach = (*xPtr + 25) % USHRT_MAX;`
      xResult = -1;

`   for (unsigned short* xPtr2 = xPtr + 1; xPtr2 != xArrayEnd; ++xPtr2)`
`        if (*xPtr2 >= xValToBreach)`
`       {`
`          xResult = (int)(xPtr2 - xArray); break;`
`        }`

 `     if (xResult == -1)`
 `       xResult = INT_MAX;`
 `     xResults[xPtr - xArray] = xResult;`
 `   }`
 ` }`